# Is it require complete groovy knowledge for developing a grails applications

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to Groovy and Grails , I saw the Grails documentation I know the basics of grails what are the files and how to run the application. But I don't know the groovy but I knew the Java language very well, can I write java syntax code in grails like constructors,method calls or shall I learn groovy If so please provide me the groovy's documentation links I want the groovy 1.8 version.

Comment: If you know Java very well you will learn groovy easily and fast. Just start coding :)

Comment: If you know Java well, then all you really need to know about Groovy is this: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started learning GRAILS then I was not very good at JAVA itself. Now, that you know JAVA language it should be pretty easy for you.

It is always better to use groovy in Grails instead of writing JAVA code as many examples and docs will be shown in groovy and would be easier for you to understand.

You could download the documentation from here: http://dist.groovy.codehaus.org/distributions/groovy-docs-1.8.9.zip

Answer (score 1):

I started with groovy 1st, and had to say, that using groovy instead of java in a web-app brings huge advantages already. Grails brings it further. So yes, in order to use the full strength of Grails you have to learn groovy

Answer (score 1):

I started both Groovy and Grails along with MongoDB 2 weeks back. Now I am developing a full fledged web service using Groovy and Grails with MongoDB in the backend. Stackoverflow has answer to most of the problems you might encounter.

Here are a few links that would be really useful:

http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners/

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/

Definitive guide to grails. You can download it from http://www.4shared.com/office/rEorQxoi/the_definitive_guide_to_grails.html?locale=en

Hope it helps.